# How to determine if a video file has been watched in full (Windows, MPC-HC)?

Tags: windows-10

I have a bunch of .mp4 and .mkv files (auto-downloaded from YouTube videos and put in a special dir).

I want to determine which of these I have "watched". And by that, I don't mean opening them once or "accessing" them, but where I've allowed the entire video to "roll out" at least once, or at least 75% of the length or something like that, which can also be considered "having seen it".

I use MPC-HC on Windows to play them.

The purpose is to determine which of the files to delete automatically. I currently base this on the file's age, which is far from ideal.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is it "possible"?  Well, sure.  Like academic test questions that use words like "always" or "never", the word "possible" is a highly charged word, which can be interpreted in the extreme.  What is more relevant to ask is, "how easy is it?"

Also, what do you mean by "watched"?  Do you watch them on YouTube, and make a copy while they are being watched, or download from YouTube in some other way?  In other words, when you say "watched", is that only watching via MPC-HC, or is watching by YouTube also something that is supposed to be counted?

For the computer to present you with information, like what videos you watched, that information will need to be recorded somehow.  Some software may do this (with a menu option like "Open recent" which then shows recently-used files).  This would most likely be done by the movie playing software, although in theory there may be alternative approaches involving noticing what files you access (effectively monitoring your usage, similar to how anti-virus software can keep track of files that gets accessed).

If the software you're using doesn't support the feature, you could modify the software (I believe MPC-HC is "open source").  This may be something many people consider infeasible, but gets to the core of answering the question about, "how easy is it to do this?"

Some of these solutions might not offer a solution for previously-watched videos, but only be a solution for going forward.

What you may wish to do is to consider another approach.  Consider these two...

One is to do manual logging.  Use a notepad window to note the filenames you watch.

The other might be to use different folders.  When you have a folder called "downloaded" and want to watch a video, start by dragging that video into the "current" folder.  Then watch the video from there.  If you get interrupted, that's fine.  Then, after finishing the video (or during some sort of daily/weekly clean-up procedure), manually drag the watched videos into another folder called "watched".

That process is a little bit more manual work than what you're probably currently doing, but not much, and you may find that solution is the simplest to implement overall.